# ¿Porqué se producen y cómo se solucionan los errores de GPG?

Tags: linux, gpg

Estaba leyendo acerca de como arreglar el error

```
W: Error de GPG: http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco InRelease:
 Las firmas siguientes no se pudieron verificar porque su clave pública no está di
sponible: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886
```

Al ejecutar el comando `apt-get update` y encontré [aquí](https://ubunlog.com/como-arreglar-el-error-w-error-de-gpg/) como arreglarlo. Pero al poner en la linea de comandos como `root` el siguiente comando:

```
apt-key adv -keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com -recv-keys C2518248EEA14886
```

me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.YmCyf4kzxZ/gpg.1.sh –keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.co
m –recv-keys C2518248EEA14886
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
usage: gpg [options] [filename]
```

Mi pregunta es por qué aparecen estos errores y cómo se solucionan en general, porque parece que no es algo salga en cualquier parte.

Comment: prueba  apt-key adv –keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com –recv-keys F59E4889

Comment: @tasiaylalo De donde se sacan los números que tú pusiste

Comment: @tasiaylalo El comando me duevuelve `gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...`

`usage: gpg [options] [filename]`

Comment: Mira a ver si te sirve este link https://superuser.com/questions/620765/sudo-apt-key-adv-keyserver-keyserver-ubuntu-com-recv-7f0ceb10-command-return

Comment: Tiene pinta de error típico de *copy/paste* con el ratón ... confirma que `--keyserver` y `--recv-keys` comienzan **con 2 guiones juntos**: `- -`

Comment: @Trauma En efecto era lo que tú decias, ya no me da el error, muchas gracias por la simple solución, aunque reformularé la pregunta porque sigo teniendo ciertas dudas

Comment: ¿ Quieres que te explique para que sirve el firmado de paquetes y repositorios ?

Comment: Es una buena idea